# App crashes on alternate runs while using NSThread for loading map

Tags: iphone, crash, mkmapview, nsthread

I am using NSThread to do some work concurrently with main thread. I've deployed the application on iPhone 3G
The application is working as expected in first run.

But, when I close the app and run it again, it crashes immediatly. The next time I run the app, it works fine again. this keeps on repeating.

I have no idea why earlier run of the app has an effect on the next run.
Please help!

Here is my code:

```
NSThread *th=[[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadMap) object:nil];
[th start]; 

-(void) loadMap{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    //code to load MKMapView

    [pool release];

}
```

Thanks in advance

**App won't crash if I open another map application in between two runs!
Also App works very fine if I remove the thread and load the map serially**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should spend time to read [thread programming reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i), about the chapter of **Thread Management**.

Comment: I have gone through Threading Programming Guide several times.

Comment: Could you please elaborate where is the mistake in the code, if you have found it?

Comment: In the document, it said that nondetached thread will be terminated directly if application quit.

Comment: And, I remember the iPhone 3G doesn't support multi-tasking, so it will terminate the app when push home button. iPhone 3GS will make your app enter background, then there may be problems when the app re-enter the foreground.

Comment: The document, page 18, section of Threads and Your User Interface recommented, run user-related events and interface initial updates from main-thread. It can avoid some known problems.

Comment: So, I think you should not load MKMapView in the child thread, if it relate UI events.

Comment: I'm just loading the map which calls google's web service. I'm not adding it as subview from child thread. So I think Its not related to UI events.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Toro. Do you have any idea how two consecutive runs of the application are related? (especially when no persistent storage is used)

Comment: App won't crash if I open another map application in between two runs! Also App works very fine if I remove the thread and load the map serially

Comment: I have no idea about two consecutive runs of the applications, sorry. I think if it will push context into context stack, then it will relate UI events about draw something in the current cg context. The cg context stack is not thread safe in my experiment. Maybe it is thread safe above iOS 4 from the document about what's new in iOS document.